# Java is visible as disabled on FF

Tags: software-installation, firefox, java

**Linux:** Ubuntu 20.04

**Web browser:** Firefox

Yesterday I was trying to use a website that most likely required Java. I was not sure if it was even installed, and - forgive my ignorance - I didnt even run "java -version" command in my Terminal.

**I auomatically assumed it is not installed and did the following:**

1. Went on https://www.java.com/en/download/
2. Downloaded from the link saying Linux x64
3. Followed instructions:
   -- gained root privilages by typing "sudo -i"
   -- changed directory to /usr/
   -- created folder "java":
   -- moved my downloaded "java" to that folder
   -- changed directory to /usr/java
   -- tar zxvf jre-8u281-linux-x64.tar.gz
   -- Checked if my Java was installed correctly:

- Terminal: java -version
- Output:
  openjdk version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9+11-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9+11-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
- Checked my Java version by going on https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-java-installed
- Output:
  No
  Java is disabled or not installed in this browser

**Additional info:**

1. In about:config the "javascript.enabled" is set to "true"
2. I tried disabling ALL firefox add-ons that could interfere with Java functionality and restarted the browser/PC - did not change anything.

**Question:**
Has anybody been in a similar situation and perhaps could help?

Comment: Java!=Javascript. IIRC, Java in browsers was deprecated with Java 9 (or may be 11).

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.  Java applet in browsers has been gone since Java 10, and has not been supported in Linux since Java 8.  Internet Explorer in Windows is the only browser left in existence that supports Java webapplets running in the Java runtime - and that's not available on Linux.  As IE phases out for Edge in Windows as well, that just is the nail in the coffin to Java WebApplets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java (and other plugins like Flash) is not supported anymore inside of the browser, at least not in the major browsers available on Linux like Chrome or Firefox. The only known bigger browser that still supports the Java Plugin is Internet Explorer I think, but of course that browser is not available on Linux.